# Is Goldstine’s theorem true for a general norm space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Goldstine’s theorem is the following:
Let X be a Banach space, then the image of the closed unit ball B ⊂ X under the canonical embedding into the closed unit ball B′′ of the bidual space X ′′ is weak*-dense.

I understand the proof by use of strictly separation theorem.
The theorem is true for locally convex topological vector space(t.v.s).A general norm space is locally convex t.v.s. So,I think whether Goldstine’s theorem is true for a general norm space.However in the Wikipedia of the Goldstine’s theorem,this theorem is not true for a norm topology.I don’t know why.Please give me a hint or answer.

Comment: Yes, it is. The Wiki article just has an unneeded hypothesis. [Here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/goldstine-s-theorem) is a proof (I haven't checked this).

Comment: Thank you. I completely understand. I have mistaken the meaning of the sentence in the wiki.